# SQL range queries with encrypted Amazon RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, encryption

I plan to use ssl transport combined with the encrypted RDS store option on amazon AWS as part of HIPAA compliance. If part of the ePHI that needs to be encrypted is appointment times, would it still be possible to query RDS start/end time **ranges** with the encryption option turned on? I can't find any documentation on AWS related to query limitations for encrypted RDS stores. The documentation does say the encryption is totally transparent to the application so it leads me to believe that all SQL queries are still valid, I just want to make sure since I know range queries usually have specific limitations in encrypted databases.

Thanks!

Comment: As with most things AWS, you can always fire up a server for an hour or two to experiment. RDS's encryption happens at the disk level, not at the database level, so any normal query should work fine. You'll be able to do `SELECT * FROM patients WHERE disease='something super embarassing'` so be mindful of access control. You really should consult your HIPAA compliance folks/auditors on this to see if you need additional steps.

Comment: My example was to illustrate that anyone with SQL access can make HIPAA-sensitive queries and get back plain-text responses. A simple SQL injection bug can cause you a reportable breach without additional safety measures like encrypting at the database level.

Comment: As already stated, an RDS encrypted database is encrypted at the disk level, not the database level. That means the database does not see the data as encrypted, and you can perform any query just as if the data was not encrypted, because it actually isn't encrypted in RAM, just in storage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encrypting RDS means the data at rest is encrypted, as are any snapshots and backups.

But when the database is running, the data is available via the db engine without any noticeable difference to the application.